# List items becomes black during scroll, setCacheColorHint() takes no effect

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a two-colored `ListView`s in my Android application (one color for odd elements and one for even). And it works just fine on Froyo. But on Jelly Bean emulator there are some artifacts appearing during scroll. Background of some elements becomes black. **Yes, I know about solution with transparent cache color hint!** But it works only if I set background in this way:

In method `bindView()` of adapter:

```
// ...
view.setBackgroundResource(
        cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 0 ? R.color.list_item_bg1: R.color.list_item_bg2);
```

But this method does not suit me since I would like to highlight element, then user taps on it. So I use `StateListDrawable` for this purpose:

```
mOddColorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_bg2));
mEvenColorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_bg1));
mSelector = new ColorDrawable(
    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_selector));

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // ...
    setBackground(cursor.getPosition % 2 != 0, view);
}

public void setBackground(boolean isOdd, View listItem) {
    StateListDrawable dr = new StateListDrawable();
    Drawable drColor = isOdd ? mOddColorDrawable : mEvenColorDrawable;
    dr.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, mSelectorDrawable);
    dr.addState(new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_pressed }, drColor);
    listItem.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
}
```

So, with this code black elements background is appearing during scroll even if I set transparent color hint for `ListView`. I spend days investigating this issue but could not overcome it. So, you are my last hope, StackOverflow!

**Summary:**

1. I would like to have ListView with two different element colors.
2. I would like to have item selector with custom color.
3. setCacheColorHint(transparent) didn't help if I use StateListDrawable.
4. Everything works just fine on Froyo, but not on Jelly Bean.

Comment: Use android:cacheColorHint = "#00000000" rather than android:cacheColorHint = "#000000"

Comment: I use setCacheColorHint(android.R.color.transparent). It's not about correct color hint. As I said before, transparent color hint helps if I use usual setBackgroundResource() isntead if StateListDrawable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make alternate background color for list item . In your adapter class write this line of code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.firstcolor);
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.second color);
            } 
         ...............
         .........
```

Hi 
For complete help go through my Android Blog hope you will find your answer as you are looking for. Just now i have done from my side and tested, its working fine for me.
At the bottom you will get a link so that you can download full source code.

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-alternate-list.html

Please let me know if it full fill your requirement.

Comment: There will not be any selector for pressed item in this case.

Comment: Amit, thanks! Solution in your blog works for me! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

set  cacheColorHint="#00000000" in your list view.

for more info .. go through this post [Getting Black Screen while Scrolling in ListView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345677/getting-black-screen-while-scrolling-in-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dynamic Listview then for avoiding black screen

```
ListView listview=new ListView();
listview.setCacheColorHint(0);
```

One more thing if you want to make transparent listitem while clicking any item it seems yellow. For avoiding this

```
listview.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0x0));
```

And for layout use
 // For avoiding Yellow color while selecting or clicking List item

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

Thanks,

Comment: Amit, I would like to have custom color for selected element. But calling listview.setSelector(R.color.blue) or listview.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(R.color.blue)) did't take any effect. There are just no any element highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this **[tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)** for more information .

Add a attribute on the ListView Tag

```
 android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"// setting as a transparent color
```

Answer (score 0):

setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0x0));
Is used to avoid yellow color while clicking listitem. If you want some hover effect to ListItem so use selctor in listiem.

listiemselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@color/selected" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/selected" />
</selector>
```

and use it in your listitem parent Layout.

```
android:background="@drawable/listiemselector"
```

Comment: In this case all items will have white background. But I want to have striped list (odd elements have one color, even - another). This is the main point!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem of list getting black colored when removing items from it. Today I have solved it by just removing the "android:background" attribute of the listView.. It works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Please use  **mListView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);** where mListView is ListView object reference. It works perfect.